# Enumerate Golang net/rpc Port?

Tags: web-application, enumeration

I'm playing with a web app CTF for fun/learning. The backend is using Golang's [net/rpc](https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc) library to provide frontend access to what I think are database operations.  The problem is I don't know what the exported services are, and as such, don't know how to call them. Is there any way to get more information on what services are being served by RPC?

Comment: Does it react on a `curl hhtp://server:port`?

Comment: @StefanLorenz no, it just hangs.

Comment: Simply, There is no built-in way to enumerate the exported services in Go's net/rpc library. what you can do, you can try brute force to get the service with different methods such as GET, and POST.